# Will Structured Streaming(DataFrames/Datasets) in PySpark be supported stateful operations?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I found out that on streaming DataFrames/Datasets in PySpark does not support stateful operations.
Link -> [Arbitrary Stateful Operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations)

I've tons of python code already. And I a bit worried about the aspect of moving our code to Scala / Java language.

Can someone clarify, will the python have stateful operations functionality in the next versions? If so when approximately will be available?

Thanks

Comment: did you find out anything related to this? I'm just set to start working on a streaming algorithm where I need state and is interested in knowning if I should go with python or scala/java... :confused:

Comment: @Daniel, no, I didn't. I moved my project to Scala.